# How to change string color into color resource?

Tags: android, material-design

I want to change my header background color and I am using the MaterialDrawer library:

```
   AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)                   
  .withHeaderBackground(Color.parseColor(mPrefs.getString("theme_color",getResources().getString(R.string.default_color)))
  .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            ... and so on
```

But with header background, I got the error message "**Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer**" and not able to set background color read from preferences. it give Error on log : "**android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2e60e8**"

Comment: as error suggest `withHeaderBackground` Expectes resource id (eg. R.id.someColor) and you are passing HEX code. that is why you are getting that error. how are you saving your color in preference?

Comment: I received HEX color code from the server and I then want to change the background color of my header

Comment: your color is in int format right ?

Comment: i am getting hex color code from server as a String .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creat ColorDrawable from your string and you can set it to your header

```
int col = Color.parseColor(mPrefs.getString("theme_color",getResources().getString(R.string.default_color)));
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable();
cd.setColor(col);

headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withCompactStyle(false)
            .withHeaderBackground(cd)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
```

Comment: i don't want to define my Hex Color in color.xml, is there is some another way to read the value from preferences.

Comment: purpose of color.xml is to store your colors in central locations, Is there any specific reason you don't want to store it there?

Comment: Does it work if you pass `#FF6666` directly to `Color.parseColor()`

Comment: can you log value of `mPrefs.getString("theme_color",getResources().getString(R.string.default_color))` and check whether it is returning your expected value?

Comment: yes i  checked it return hex color code value those i set remotely

Comment: @KarishmaPatel : Check updated answer it should work as you are expecting.

Comment: it set white background color  but in log, I got value is " #2E60E8"

Comment: as it is returning value, I have updated answer accordingly, check if it is allowing you to set the color.

Comment: revert to previous code where it was setting white background and make sure you are using latest version of library.

Comment: still not update color.. and i am using the latest version of library.

Comment: @KarishmaPatel: I have updated answer and tested it with demo app, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Save the color HEX code in colors.xml like this:
       #AABBEE (use the color's hex code here)
Then, set the background:

```
  .withHeaderBackground(R.color.myColor)
  .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
  ....
```

Comment: I want to use string color resources not from color.xml  file color code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should mention in the question that you are using the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library, since `AccountHeader` is not a part of the standard Android SDK.

That said, examining the source of `AccountHeaderBuilder` in the repo shows that there are 3 variants for the `withHeaderBackground` method, that take a `Drawable`, a `@DrawableRes int` and a `ImageHolder` respectively.

If you are insistent on loading the color from `strings.xml`, then I think the following method would work:

Create a `ColorDrawable` using your string, which should be formatted as `0xAARRGGBB`

Since the `ColorDrawable` class extends `Drawable`, it should be a valid argument for the `withHeaderBackground` method. Your code would look like this:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getString(R.string.default_color));

AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)                   
  .withHeaderBackground(cd)
  .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            ... and so on
```

A simpler method would be to simply have a `drawable` resource and use that as `R.drawable.default_drawable` instead.

Comment: above code is not working getting error :android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2e60e8

Comment: Um, this is according to the sample code you gave. Ensure that there is a string with the id `default_color` in `strings.xml`. If you are getting your string from a server, as you mentioned in a comment above, then obviously there won't be anything in your xml file. You would have to pass that in place of `getResource().getString(R.string.default_color)`

Answer (score 0):

`Color.parseColor()` parse the color string, and return the corresponding **color-int**, this int value is different from **resource ID**, even two values are also `int` type.

You could do like this:

```
int colorID =
    getResourceID("your_color_name", "color", getApplicationContext());
```

No needs for using `Color.parseColor()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `withHeaderBackground()` you're using is this:

```
public AccountHeaderBuilder withHeaderBackground(@DrawableRes int headerBackgroundRes)
```

but you're passing an `int` value of some color.  
You need a color or drawable resource id.

Answer (score -1):

### You can do this in Two steps

Lets say you have a color #8080000

**1. Convert your Hex to int first**

```
int yourColor = Color.parseColor("#808000");
```

**2. Set Background**

```
.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(yourColor));
```